# Etymology of the name Laurentius

Tags: etymology

**[Laurentius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurentius)** is a Latin name that means "From Laurentum" (a city near Rome). It is possible that the place name Laurentum is derived from the Latin laurus ("laurel"). The Greek form Λαυρέντιος (Lauréntios) is derived from Latin Laurentius

In the same time, **[Lorenz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz)** is an originally German name derived from the Roman surname, Laurentius, which mean "from Laurentum" or Old Greek word Lavrenti meaning "bright one, shining one".

And then, is it possible that the words Laurentius, Laurentum, Laurus and Lauréntios come from the Old Greek word Lavrenti?

Comment: The "Old Greek word Lavrenti" in that article is unsourced and certainly nonsense.